# CSS Keyframe animation breaks select element

Tags: css, css-animations, html-select

I wanted to add a slight, occasional, glow to focused elements for part of an app I'm building. Interestingly, it breaks `select` elements - after focusing the `select`, while hovering the `option`s, there's a "jumpy" behavior to the hovered options, which makes it <strike>impossible to properly choose</strike> jump around which option is highlighted, but is actually selecting the correct option.

Relevant code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes glow {
    0%{
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 #35ABFF;
    }
    8%{
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 #35ABFF;
    }
    16%{
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 #35ABFF;          
    }
    100%{
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 #35ABFF;          
    }
}
input:focus, select:focus{
    -webkit-animation: glow 5.5s ease-out infinite;
}
```

Removing the webkit animation from the elements causes it to go back to the normal behavior.

I'm also (I know it's wrong) running a `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` on the `body`. It doesn't seem to be relevant, as removing it does not fix the issue. I've also tried `webkit-backface-visibility` (my standard go-to for webkit animation quirkiness) but no cigar.

So far, I've only seen it in Chrome on Windows, as that's my dev environment.

Has anyone else seen this behavior, and is there a fix?

Thanks